# Asp.net Mvc, Razor and Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, localization

I know this matter has already been brought on these pages many times, but still I haven't found the "good solution" I am required to find. Let's start the explanation.

Localization in .net, and in mvc, is made in 2 ways that can even be mixed together:

- Resource files (both local or global)
- Localized views with a viewengine to call the appropriate view based on culture

I'll explain the solutions I tried and all the problems I got with every one of them.

**Text in resource files, all tags in the view**

This solution would have me put every text in resources, and every tag in the view, even the inline tags such as [strong] or [span].

Pros:

- Clean separation, no structure whatsoever in localization.
- Easy encoding: everything that is returned from the resource gets html encoded.

Cons:

- If I have a paragraph with some strongs, a couple of link etc I have to split it in many resource keys. This is considered to make the view too unreadable and also takes too much time to create it.
- For the same reason as above, if in two different languages the [strong] text is in different places (like "Il **cane** di Marco" and "Marcos's **dog**"), I can't achieve it, since all my tags are in the view.

**Text and inline tags in resource files, through parameters**

This method will have the resources contain some placeholders for string.Format, and those placeholders will be filled with inline tags post-encoding.

Pros:

- Clean separation, with just placeholders in the text, so if I am ever to replace [strong] with [em] I do it in the view where I pass it as parameter and it gets changed in every language

Cons:

- Encoding is a bit harder, I have to pre-encode the value from the resource, then use string.Format, and finally return it as MvcHtmlString to tell the view engine to not re-encode it when displaying.
- For the same reason as above, including, for instance, an ActionLink as parameter would be troublesome. Let's say I get the text for my actionlink from a resource. My method already encodes it. But then, the ActionLink method would re-encode it again. I would need a distinct method to get resources without encoding them, or new helper methods that get an MvcHtmlString instead of a string as text parameter, but both are rather unpractical.
- Still takes a whole lot of time to build views, having to create all the resource keys and then fill them.

**Localized views**

Pros:

- All views are plain html. No resources to read.

Cons:

- Duplicated html everywhere. I don't even need to explain how this is totally evil.
- Have to manually encode all troublesome characters like grave vowels, quotes and such.

**Conclusions**

A mix of the above techinques inherits pros and cons, but it's still no good. I am challenged to find a proper productive solution, while all of the above are considered "unpractical" and "time consuming".

To make things worse, I found out that there isn't a single tool that refactors "text" from aspx or cshtml (or even html) views/pages into resources. All the tools out there can refactor System.String instances in code files (.cs or .vb) into resources only (resharper for instance, and a couple of others I can't remember now).

So I'm stuck, can't find anything appropriate on my own, and can't find anything on the web either. Is it possible noone else got challenged with this problem before and found a solution?

Comment: Did you pick a solution for this? I'm curious what you went with.

Comment: Actually the topic got frozen at work. I proposed the integration of Markdown, it could be an improvement but someone still not convinced. I know that localization in .Net is done that way and I personally never had problems with it, but still, it's not convincing to the people I'm working with now.

Comment: That sucks. I like plain text markup geneartion because it's both human and machine readable :). I just got my blog up and running using Markdown all over the place. http://www.codetunnel.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally like the idea of storing inline tags in the resource file. However I do it a little differently. I store very plain tags like `<span class='emphasis'>dog</span>` and then I use CSS to style the tags appropriately. Now, instead of "passing in" a tag as a parameter, I simply style the `span.emphasis` rule in my CSS appropriately. Change carries over to all languages.

---

**The Sexier Option:**

Another option I thought of and quite enjoy is to use a "readable markup" language like StackOverflow's very own [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/). This way you aren't storing any HTML in the resource file, only markdown text. So in your resource you would have `**dog**` and then it gets shunted through markdown in the view (I created a helper for this, (Usage: `Html.Markdown(string text)`). Now you're not storing tags, you're storing a common human readable markup language. The markdownsharp source is one .CS file and it's easy to modify. So you could always change the way it renders the ending HTML. This gives you total control over all your resources without storing HTML, and without duplicating views or chunks of HTML.

**EDIT**

This also gives you control over the encoding. You could easily make sure the content of your resource files contain no valid HTML. Markdown syntax (as you know from using stack overflow) does not contain HTML tags and thus can be encoded without harm. Then you just use your helper to convert the Markdown syntax to valid HTML.

**EDIT #2**

There is one bug in markdown that I had to fix myself. Anything markdown detects is to be rendered as a "code" block will be HTML encoded. This is a problem if you have already HTML encoded all content being passed to markdown as anything in the code blocks will be essentially re-encoded which turns `&gt;` into `&amp;gt;` and completely screws up the text within code blocks. To fix this I modified the markdown.cs file to include a boolean option that stops markdown from encoding text within code blocks. [See this issue](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/issues/detail?id=43) for the fixed .cs file that I added to the MarkdownSharp project issues.

**EDIT #3** - Html Helper Sample

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Markdown(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
    {
        var markdown = new MarkdownSharp.Markdown
        {
            AutoHyperlink = true,
            EncodeCodeBlocks = false, // This option is my custom option to stop the code block encoding problem.
            LinkEmails = true,
            EncodeProblemUrlCharacters = true
        };
        string html = markdown.Transform(markdownText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, although there is one thing that puzzles me. Both aspx <%: and Razor @ symbols automatically encode System.String and DO NOT encode System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString. Since the transform method of Markdown returns string, I don't see how your fix could potentially cause any trouble. I would call @Html.Transform(string) and the razor engine would encode the output.

Comment: You don't call `Html.Transform(string)` you call custom helper `@Html.Markdown(string)` which so happens to return `MvcHtmlString`. See EDIT #3 for sample.

Comment: On a second thought, I wrote something wrong. I should first encode what I retrieve from my resource, then transform it, and finally return an MvcHtmlString so the view engine does not re-encode it.

Comment: Lol thought the same thing. You're quite something, dude.

Comment: This is going to kill you performance-wise, unless you do at least some output caching.

Comment: @kprobst I currently use this and it has not hurt performance. The MarkdownSharp project even comes with a test project that runs several tests on the library and measures performance. There are no significant drawbacks in performance when using MarkdownSharp. It completes its tasks in milliseconds, even with large input strings.

Comment: Heh, thanks for the compliment! Encoding before transform works too and would be easily added to the helper. Just do `text = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(text);` at the start of the helper method.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing stops you from storing HTML in resource files, then calling `@Html.Raw(MyResources.Resource)`.

Comment: That's not an option, and I stated why in my post. If I do as you suggest, then I have to manually encode special characters in the resx file (like agrave, egrave, quote, ecc). I want to be able to write normally in my resx files (to be more translator-friendly) and then the view engine does the encoding.

Comment: @Matteo, see my answer with MarkdownSharp. With it you could write cleanly in the resource file and then use a custom helper to render it as markdown. `@Html.Markdown(MyResources.Resource)`.

Comment: I was just looking into that. I'll experiment a bit and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Matteo Mosca: You could also implement a helper function, e.g. `@Html.EncodeText(MyResources.Resource)`, which encodes only text and not markup (can be implemented with regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using localized models, have your view be strongly types to IMyModel and then pass in the appropriately decorated model then  you can use/change how your doing your localization fairly easy by modifying the appropriated model.

it's clean, very flexible, and very easy to maintain.

you could start out with Recourse file based localization and then for paces you need to update more often switch that model to a cached DB based localization model.